# Python 3.7.1 Pygame 1.9.4 Error: TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, pygame

So, I was building a really simple game. I was going to make a circle jump. Until that all worked fine. But when I tried adding jumping to the game, an error messege appeared, telling me, "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float" I checked the code multiple times. I couldn't seem to find the error. So I am asking for help. Here's my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("A GAME")

screenWidth = 500

x = 100
y = 400
width = 50
height = 50
vel = 10
r = 15

isJump = False

jumpCount = 10

run = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    clock.tick(60)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys [pygame.K_a] and x > r:
        x -= vel
    if keys [pygame.K_d] and x < screenWidth - r:
        x += vel
    if not (isJump):
        if keys [pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    if keys [pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))


    pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), r, 0)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

plz help

Comment: pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), r, 0) should be pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, int(y)), r, 0) as y is a float

Comment: There is only one float: `0.5`. That turns the entire expession into a float. Try `y -= (jumpCount * jumpCount) // 2 * neg` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y), r, 0)
```

should be changed to:

```
pygame.draw.circle(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, int(y)), r, 0)
```

as y is a float after this line:

```
y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
```

or you could fix it like this:

```
y -= int((jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg)
```

Rudy's answer will work as well as the output of floor division(//) is an int:

```
y -= (jumpCount ** 2) // 2 * neg
```

Answer (score 0):

The only `float` in your code is `y`; you'll probably want something like

```
y -= int((jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

The use of 0.5 turns your y into a float. I guess that is not what you want. So turn that into:

```
y -= (jumpCount * jumpCount) // 2 * neg
```